# WCF ChannelFactory configuration outside of App.config?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-configuration

I've got a Windows Service that makes use of a plugin system.  I'm using the following code in the plugin base class to provide a separate configuration per DLL (so it'll read from `plugin.dll.config`):

```
string dllPath = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location;
return ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(dllPath);
```

These plugins need to make calls to WCF services, so the problem I'm running into is that `new ChannelFactory<>("endPointName")` only looks in the hosted application's App.config for the endpoint configuration.

**Is there a way to simply tell the ChannelFactory to look in another configuration file or somehow inject my `Configuration` object?**

The only way I can think of to approach this is to manually create an EndPoint and Binding object from values read in from `plugin.dll.config` and pass them to one of the `ChannelFactory<>` overloads.  This really seems like recreating the wheel though, and it could get really messy with an endPoint that makes heavy use of behavior and binding configurations.  **Perhaps there's a way to create EndPoint and Binding objects easily by passing it a configuration section?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 options.

**Option 1.  Working with channels.**

If you are working with channels directly, .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 has the [ConfigurationChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd575311%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  The example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960149%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) looks like this:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "Test.config";
Configuration newConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    fileMap,
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

ConfigurationChannelFactory<ICalculatorChannel> factory1 = 
    new ConfigurationChannelFactory<ICalculatorChannel>(
        "endpoint1", 
        newConfiguration, 
        new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/servicemodelsamples/service"));
ICalculatorChannel client1 = factory1.CreateChannel();
```

As pointed out by Langdon, you can use the endpoint address from the configuration file by simply passing in null, like this:

```
var factory1 = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<ICalculatorChannel>(
        "endpoint1", 
        newConfiguration, 
        null);
ICalculatorChannel client1 = factory1.CreateChannel();
```

This is discussed in the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd575430.aspx).

**Option 2.  Working with proxies.**

If you're working with code-generated proxies, you can read the config file and load a [ServiceModelSectionGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicemodelsectiongroup.aspx).  There is a bit more work involved than simply using the `ConfigurationChannelFactory` but at least you can continue using the generated proxy (that under the hood uses a `ChannelFactory` and manages the `IChannelFactory` for you.

Pablo Cibraro shows a nice example of this here: [Getting WCF Bindings and Behaviors from any config source](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/05/11/getting-wcf-bindings-and-behaviors-from-any-config-source.aspx)

Comment: I was disappointed at first because the ctor required you to define an EndpointAddress, which the endpoint already defines, and then I realized you can send `null` and it'll use the configured address.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: True.  I forgot to mention that.  Let me edit the response and make it clear.

Answer (score 4):

Use a separate AppDomain for each plugin.  When you create the AppDomain you can specify a new configuration file.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I found to my 2nd question... someone put the work in to read all the data from `ServiceModelSectionGroup` and create a `ChannelFactory`.

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx

I'll be using Richard's solution though, as it seems much cleaner.